# Is it possible to change the red button of youtube?

Tags: ios7, uiwebview

My app plays YouTube video clips which are embedded within UIWebViews. My question is: Can I replace the play button (red button) as another button? Or change its color? If ok, how to handle this button when user touch it to Youtube can run?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to have custom UI, you can use YouTube API

Comment: @Raptor: Can you please give me tutorial for this? I tried to do with js and css. However it did not work in my app. I think it is impossible for iOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Seek tutorial in Google and in YouTube API site.